# Кто пишет бесплатные программы?

Tags: лицензирование

Вопрос из тех, которые появляются в 2 часа ночи... Кому выгодно писать бесплатные программы и тратить на них время?
Конечно, есть разные виды ПО. Одни могут быть trial-версиями, другие условно бесплатными (например, с ограничениями в функционале).
Но в я имею в виду программы, которые можно считать полностью бесплатными. Только ли альтруизм и чистая инициатива?

Одно из моих предположений заключается в том, что программисты когда-то написали необходимую для их целей программу и решили поделиться с другими.

Comment: Вставлю свои пять копеек. Думаю в этом есть смысл, типо, либо автор так захотел (может в надежде на донат, либо в качестве практики), либо это кому-то нужно было (имеется ввиду компании), она с этого имеет какую-то выгоду (данные, посещения, что угодно), а программист сделал её платно.

Comment: Вы с этим знание чего дальше собираетесь делать? Я вам могу так сказать, что программист преследует как меркантильные, так и/или альтруистические цели

Comment: Бесплатные программы пишут те же люди, которые бесплатно комментируют вопросы и отвечают на них на этом сайте.

Comment: @A B  В России бесплатные программы это неизбежность.  Платные все равно никто не покупает -  берут ломаные версии (если прога нужная - ее всегда взломают).  В России нет культуры покупки продуктов интеллектуального труда. Все привыкли к халяве.  За рубежом же деньги просят за любую простецкую прожку, даже если это тупо батник. И ведь люди считают нормальным платить (еще и потому что за использование ломанного софта могут хорошо штрафануть).  Так что твой вопрос очень наивен. Ты сам-то хоть одну прогу покупал?

Comment: @Garry Galler Не все, но опыт покупки есть. Просто то, что лежит бесплатно, зачастую, потом используется для получения личной выгоды. А труды человека, сделавшего что-то ни во что не ставят. Вот так и получается, что не понятно было, какая практическая цель всего этого... Целая философия получается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такое понятие, как Open Source разработка: [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Открытое_программное_обеспечение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Это целая философия, обычно openSource используется в:

1. Блокчейн (тут нужно чтобы платформе доверяли пользователи, поэтому исходный кодд открывают, да и просто по-другому не получится)
2. Движки и библиотеки (некоторые устарели, а некоторые изначально были бесплатны, это удобно) TensorFlow, Google Kubernetes, Apache Spark, OpenCV
3. Языки программирования и IDE (вот почему то так получилось, отдали людям в пользование :) ) VS Code, Rust, Node.js, Go
4. Linux (так захотел так разработчик)

В общем почи все, что вы захотите можно в том или ином виде найти в Open Source) И это замечательно, как по мне

Comment: Хоть как-то упомяните и основателя движения -- [RMS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD,_%D0%A0%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4_%D0%9C%D1%8D%D1%82%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E) с его FSF и GNU / (Кстати, Linux основан на GNU и поэтому принципиально не мог не быть open)

Comment: Ну да, с Linux не совсем верно, всё упомянуть невозможно, спасибо за замечание)